# $p(x)x^n+q(x)(1-x)^n=1$ for some $p(x), q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, what explicitly $p(x), q(x)$ are?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Because $x^n$ and $(x-1)^n$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so 
$p(x)x^n+q(x)(1-x)^n=1$ for some $p(x), q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. What are the explicit formulas of $p(x), q(x)$?

Comment: @Macavity I try Euclidean algorithm， but the formula seems to be very complicated.

Comment: @Macavity Also, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, I am not even sure whether Euclidean algorithm makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps you need to convince yourself Euclidean algorithm works for integers first, then look at $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: I don't know of explicit formulas, but you can get recursive formulas. The  general principle at hand is that if $a$ and $b$ are two elements of a commutative ring $R$ satisfying $aR + bR = R$, then $a^nR + b^mR = R$ for any nonnegative integers $n$ and $m$. There is an easy proof of this in two steps: first, prove it for the case $n = 1$ by induction on $m$; then, prove it for general $n$ by induction on $n$. Both inductions lead to recursive formulas for the required cofactors. Whether you can solve the recursions explicitly is a different story.

Comment: I think the adjugate of the Sylvester matrix of $x^n$ and $\left(1-x\right)^n$ also has something interesting to say, but I'm lacking the time to find out what.

Comment: A nice question. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a closed form in the more general case when you have two distinct exponents
$n$ and $m$ :

$$
(1-x)^n\Bigg(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+j-1}{j}x^j\Bigg)
-x^m\Bigg(n\binom{n+m-1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k}}{m+k}x^k\Bigg)=1. 
$$

You can also rewrite this more compactly as

$$
(1-x)^n\Bigg(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+j-1}{j}x^j\Bigg)
+x^m\Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{m+k-1}{k}(1-x)^k\Bigg)=1. 
$$

Comment: Wow! Where does this come from?

Comment: @lhf see orangeskid's answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

Start with the equality $$x+(1-x)=1$$ raise to a large enough power ( $2n-1$ will do it ), and use Newton binomial formula. Separate the LHS into a multiple of $x^n$ and a multiple of $(1-x)^n$.

Comment: Nice ! I consider this an improved version of my earlier answer here, +1.